# Visual Studio Xamarin with C# and XAML: Alternative to WPF-like Data Bindig?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, data-binding

I'm creating a simple App in which some view elements are generated programmatically on runtime. I want some of the properties of these views to be bound to data (text for example), but I do not know how this is done in Android.

I'm familiar with WPF, where this is achieved with `Data Binding`, but this is not supported in Xamarin (unless I use something 3rd party like MVVMCross, which I'd rather avoid or an approach like [THIS](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1070662/data-binding-in-xamarin-android)). So my qustion is: What is the best way to bind UI elements to data in Android? What is the common practise in, say, Android Studio, and how could I implement it in Xamarin with C#? 
I have something like [THIS](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) in mind, but this is Android Studio (I guess), so it won't work in Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add your own implementation to do this if you don't want to use a third part library, Microsoft has data binding in wpf because they implemented it, Xamarin is just a wrapper around android, and android doesn't have this functionality as far as I know. It's sort of like how JavaScript doesn't support data binding but angular does, it's a third party thing most of the time. That said, to answer your question better, your options are use third party or implement your own library.

Comment: Yes, all my internet sources seem to suggest that Data Binding is not how data is linked to thr UI in Android. I'm still interested in the Android way of handling this, but now I'm more convinced that I will have to decide on a 3rd party software.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that way anyway, hopefully what I said was helpful!

Comment: Yes it was! Upon further reseach, it seems that Android also takes this 3rd party aproach either with Binding Libraries or different extensions. So natively, this does not seem to be supported. I'm gonna do the same then!